# Create a loop in R that allows me to apply a function always to e.g. 200 elements of a vector scaling down of one element each time

Tags: r

I am having some trouble figuring out how to create a loop for a fix amount of observations.
I have a database of 500 returns, and I would like to create a loop that allows me to apply a certain function (e.g. mean, sd, qnorm, VaR) to 250 elements each time, and scaling down by one each time the loop is applied, so the first time it would be applied on observations 1-250, the second time to 2-251 etc..

I tried to understand tapply but I'm not sure that's the correct way to solve the issue
Could someone kindly help me? Thanks!!

Comment: Look at ?rollapply  in the zoo package.

Answer (score 0):

A small example using `rollapply()`:

```r
library(zoo)
# make a vector of length 500
set.seed(1)
x <- rnorm(500)

# calculate mean in windows of length 250
rollapply(x, width = 250, FUN = mean)
```